# .net core 3.1 not listed in target frameworks

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I want to change my target framework from .net core 3.0 to 3.1 preview, but it is not listed.  I am running VS 2019 v16.1.9 and have installed both .net core 3.1 sdk and release.  Restarted the computer, but 3.1 is not listed.  How do I change to .net core 3.1?

Thank you.

Comment: did you install the runtime? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: I have a solution with multiple projects.  For some reason, only one of the projects has Core 3.1 as an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now, the .Net core 3.1 is in preview. This means, by default no preview version of SDK will be enabled in VS IDE. However, you can override this default IDE behavior through enabling preview versions of .Net core SDK. There is an option in `VS IDE Tools -> Options` that enables preview versions of the .NET Core SDK. You must restart after enabling this to see the change.

Note: You must also update your Visual Studio IDE to version 16.4 which includes .NET Core 3.1. Special thanks to Hans Passant.

[image]

Comment: You also have to tell him to update VS, version 16.4 preview required.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thank you and the post is updated as commented.

Comment: I have VS 2019 v 16.4.2 and installed .Net Core 3.1 SDK. I don't see .NET Core 3.1 in an existing Console App project's Target Framework, but do see it if I create a new project that is a Console App. The existing project is currently on .NET 4.8 Framework.

Comment: I have VS 2019 v 16.4.4 and created a blazor web assembly app.  My target framework is .net standard 2.1 for some reason and don't see any .net core frameworks even though I have the latest installed as of 2/10/2020.  How do I change the target framework here?  (I do have previews enabled in vs tools/options

Answer (score 3):

> I am running **VS 2019 v16.1.9** and have installed both .net core 3.1
>   sdk and release

Your Visual Studio version is too old. You need at [least 16.4 (currently in preview channel)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-1-preview-3/):

> Visual Studio 16.4 Preview 5 and Visual Studio for Mac 8.4 Preview 5
>   are also releasing today. They are required updates to use .NET Core
>   3.1 Preview 3. Visual Studio 16.4 includes .NET Core 3.1, so just updating Visual Studio to 16.4 Preview 5 will give you the latest
>   version of both products.

Answer (score 0):

Installed 32 version of dotnet core and it works. But it is not what people want. 64 version should be visible not 32 version only.